# Integration using hyperbolic substitution

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions, substitution

I'm asked to integrate $\int{dx\over x^2 - 9}$ using hyperbolic substitution. Using the relation cosh^2-1 = sinh^2, I let x = 3cosh(u), and through simplification, arrived at $\int$ ${1\over 3 csch(u)}du$. I integrated and got $1\over 3$ln(tanh(${u \over 2}$)+c. This is where I'm stuck, as I don't know how to convert back into terms of 'x' from 'u'. If anyone could help me out, it would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn

Comment: you almost have it, but you have to enclose mathjax in dollar signs, for example `$1+1\ne2$` shows up as $1+1\ne2$

Comment: I think I've got it now, I was testing it to see if clicking "save" applied the edits (I quickly learned it did not haha)

Answer (score 0):

best method is to use partial fractions
$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{x^2-9}dx\\=\frac{1}{6}\int\left(\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x+3}\right)dx\\
=\frac{1}{6}(\ln|x-3|-\ln|x+3|)\\
=\frac{1}{6}\ln|(x-3)/(x+3)|+C
\end{align}$$

Comment: I realize that, this question requires me to use hyperbolic substitution for practice. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to go is to apply [inverse hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function) (similar to arcsine and friends).  Then \begin{align}
x &= 3 \cosh u  \\
\frac{x}{3} &= \cosh u  \\
\cosh^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{3} \right) &= u  \text{.}
\end{align}
Analogous to the inverse (circular) trigonometric functions, one should remember that this inverse function has a restricted domain, $[1,\infty)$, which can cause similar surprises.

Then it's useful to know the alternative forms of the arc-hyperbolic functions.  For arc hyperbolic cosine, you want $$ \cosh^{-1} \alpha = \ln(\alpha + \sqrt{\alpha^2 - 1})  $$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much!

Comment: I've followed your steps to the tee and understand all of them, but I'm not sure how to tie it in to tan(${u\over 2]

Comment: ** tanh(${u \over 2}$ sorry. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking I could use a hyperbolic half angle ID to pull it out of tanh and into cosh. Then, I could use the cosh value to relate it back into x. Does that seem logical?

Comment: You seem to be asking for $\tanh \frac{u}{2} = \tanh \frac{\cosh^{-1} (x/3)}{2}$.  Perhaps you mean to ask about half angle formulas for hyperbolic functions, for instance $\tanh \frac{u}{2} = \frac{\sinh u}{\cosh(u)+1} = \frac{\sinh(\cosh^{-1} (x/3))}{\cosh(\cosh^{-1} (x/3))+1}$.  Now set up your triangles the same way you would in trigonometry to deal with the analogous expressions $\sin \cos^{-1}(x/3)$ and $\cos \cos^{-1}(x/3)$.  (Note that these triangles have a point on a hyperbola, not on the unit circle.)

Comment: Will do, thanks for the guidance!